# TikZ - Edges not positioned properly when using \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, loops

I want to draw a graph like this:

[image: 1]

Which I can do well enough with the following code:

```
\node[circle,draw] (v) at (0,0) {$v$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \node[circle,draw] (u_\i) at (180 - 360/6 * \i:2cm) {$u_\i$};
    \draw (u_\i) -- (v);
}
\draw (u_1) -- (u_2);
\draw (u_2) -- (u_3);
\draw (u_3) -- (u_4);
\draw (u_4) -- (u_5);
\draw (u_5) -- (u_6);
\draw (u_6) -- (u_1);
```

But I want to be able to draw it with a \foreach loop for all of the outer edges instead of doing them one by one, like this:

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \draw let \n{j} = {Mod(\i,6)+1}
    in (u_\i) -- (u_\n{j});
}
```

However, when I try and do it this way, I end up with a graph looking like this:
[image: 2]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \node[circle,draw] (v) at (0,0) {$v$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
        \node[circle,draw] (u_\i) at (180 - 360/6 * \i:2cm) {$u_\i$};
        \draw (u_\i) -- (v);
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
        \draw let \n{j} = {Mod(\i,6)+1}
        in (u_\i) -- (u_\n{j});
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to do this with a \foreach loop, without all the edges getting messed up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You get floating point numbers like `5.0` from your computation, where `.0` gets interpreted as the east anchor. So you basically need to wrap the result in `int`, and you can do this without calc like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (v) at (0,0) {$v$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \node[circle,draw] (u_\i) at (180 - 360/6 * \i:2cm) {$u_\i$};
    \draw (u_\i) -- (v);
}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(mod(\i,6)+1)}] in {1,...,6}
{
    \draw   (u_\i) -- (u_\j);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This also results from you MWE if you add `int`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \node[circle,draw] (v) at (0,0) {$v$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
        \node[circle,draw] (u_\i) at (180 - 360/6 * \i:2cm) {$u_\i$};
        \draw (u_\i) -- (v);
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
        \draw let \n{j} = {int(Mod(\i,6)+1)}
        in (u_\i) -- (u_\n{j});
    }
}
\end{document}
```

However, IMHO this is slightly more complicated than the version without calc.

Comment: Another solution for the second loop without calc: `\foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 6)] in {1,...,6} \draw (u_\lasti) -- (u_\i);`